# How to calculate how many words are on one line within Vim/gVim?

Tags: vim, vi

How to calculate how many words are on one line within Vim/gVim?

It is kind of hard to do it manually.

It would also be nice to exclude " { } *. Essentially a word is something that begins with a letter. And words are space separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the line you want to count and do (change the matching pattern as you want):

```
:s/\<[a-zA-Z]//gn
```

This won't replace anything, just will output something like `3 matches on 1 line`.

`g` `ctrl-g` counts `{}*` as well, so you can use it if you don't want to avoid special characters.

Comment: what does "<" mean in the %s/\<[a-zA-Z]//gn ?

Comment: @vehomzzz `\<` means word-begin.

Comment: I've tried this solution on one line of the help file eval.txt: `:for c in split(mystring, '\zs')`, and it gives an incorrect result, while it gives a correct result when I paste the line in an empty buffer. Use `\w\+` (or `\h\+` ) instead! That's because `\<' delimits keywords and not words.

Comment: @Luc it prints `6 matches on 1 line` as well as `\w\+` does. What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited my previous comment instead of adding a new one. I've found the explanation of the *oddity*: `\<` doesn't match the beginning of words but of keywords. `\h\+` will always give the result you were looking for with your method.

Comment: @Luc: I think you're getting confused with the "iskeyword" option, it doesn't do what you think it does. Read `:help \<` and `:help isk` carefully.

Comment: @Luc from the help: `\<      Matches the beginning of a word:`

Comment: I also read: *The 'iskeyword' option specifies what is a word character.*, and `:h /\k` says: *`\k` keyword character (see 'iskeyword' option)*. Looks like the doc is quite imprecise of those terms (*word* vs *keyword*). On a very technical level, `\<` is closely related to `\k` as the doc says, while the pattern you use ([A-Za-z]) is another pattern: `\h`. Hence the odd result when isk is set to something that is programming related.

Answer (score 1):

```
:echo len(split(getline('.'), '\W\+')) " or \H if you want to ignore numbers as well
```

The anwser is in the help: `:h split()`

Comment: Seems preferable to regex solution for getting result into a variable.

Comment: Indeed. It depends on the objective: have a quick result for us to use, or to implement something else based on this number of words.